# clear sql server replication files

Tags: sql-server, replication

We're doing a full backup of each of our production databases every night.

We also have an hour replication occuring during the day to a report database.

It looks like the unc share ran out of space today.  Is there an automated delete feature for the replication files?  Or do I need to manually delete the replication folders that I no longer need to preserve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience,
You just need to clean up some space to make sure there is enough space for UNC share. Then start the replication again.